# Regression Line in different Excel Charts

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A                B           C         D            E           F
1    X-Values       Y-Values      
2    Year           Revenue         X-Ø       Y-Ø    (X-Ø) x (Y-Ø)  (X-Ø)^2
3    2012              10          -1.5       -55        82.5       2.25
4    2013              50          -0.5       -15         7.5       0.25
5    2014              80           0.5        15         7.5       0.25
6    2015             120           1.5        55        82.5       2.25
7
8    2013.5            65                                 180        5.0
9
10   Slope:               36.00 (=180/5.0)
11   Y-Intercept:    -72,421    (=65 - 36 x 2013.5)
12
```

In **Area A3:B6** you can see the **Year** and the corresponding **Revenue**. Now I want to make a simple trend analysis for it. Therefore, I manually calculated the **Regression Line** in **Area C3:F6** and in **Cell B10** (*Slope*) and **Cell B11** (*Y-Intercept*) which leads to the following formula:

```
y = 36X - 72,421
```

Now I want to do the same thing with an Excel chart. First I put the data in **Area A3:B6** in a **Scatter Chart** and I got the following formula for the **Regression Line**: *(Matches exactly the manual calculated formula)*

**Scatter Chart:**

[image]

When I put the same data into a **Line Chart** I get a different formula for the **Regression Line**:

**Line Chart:**

[image]

Why does the formula from the **Line Chart** differ from the **Scatter Chart** and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the scatter chart the value of `x` is the value for the year, so the values are `2012`, `2013`, `2014`, `2015`.

On the line chart the values of `x` are `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, with the year being the label for the `x` value.